# hexo s and occur Unexpected tag

Tags: node.js, hexo

When I create a tag and use it in a template, it returns an error, and I don't know why.

> Error: Unexpected tag "locationAddr '', 'Test Address'" on line 10 in file /Users/qhe/Documents/GitHub/alanhg.github.io/themes/next/layout/archive.swig.
>
> at Object.exports.throwError

I use hexojs and hexo-theme-next.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tags need to use in posts (*.md files), not in NexT swig templates.

If you want to use JS code in templates, need to create [helpers](https://hexo.io/docs/helpers).